# Memory Demands: Heap vs Stack in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

So I had a strange experience this evening.

I was working on a program in C++ that required some way of reading a long list of simple data objects from file and storing them in the main memory, approximately 400,000 entries.  The object itself is something like:

```
class Entry
{
public:
    Entry(int x, int y, int type);
    Entry(); ~Entry();
    // some other basic functions
private:
    int m_X, m_Y;
    int m_Type;
};
```

Simple, right?  Well, since I needed to read them from file, I had some loop like

```
Entry** globalEntries;
globalEntries = new Entry*[totalEntries];
entries = new Entry[totalEntries];// totalEntries read from file, about 400,000
for (int i=0;i<totalEntries;i++)
{
    globalEntries[i] = new Entry(.......);
}
```

That addition to the program added about 25 to 35 megabytes to the program when I tracked it on the task manager.  A simple change to stack allocation:

```
Entry* globalEntries;
globalEntries = new Entry[totalEntries];
for (int i=0;i<totalEntries;i++)
{
    globalEntries[i] = Entry(.......);
}
```

and suddenly it only required 3 megabytes.  Why is that happening?  I know pointer objects have a little bit of extra overhead to them (4 bytes for the pointer address), but it shouldn't be enough to make THAT much of a difference.  Could it be because the program is allocating memory inefficiently, and ending up with chunks of unallocated memory in between allocated memory?

Comment: It *looks* like you're leaking `entries`, and you could be leaking everything else, but there isn't enough code to know for sure.

Comment: It's not a leak.  I went into the debugger to make sure that the block of code to allocate the memory isn't called more than once.  Each entry is only allocated once, in sequence, in a loop.  And I have a visual representation of all of the entries.

Comment: That doesn't mean you don't have a leak. If you allocate stuff and you don't delete it, you have a leak. Note that you don't even seem to use the stuff you could be leaking.

Comment: The call to allocate the memory is called once at the beginning of runtime, and the entries are then used continuously throughout the program.

Comment: Your code doesn't show that. It shows you allocating stuff with `new` or `new []` (some of which you don't use) and never calling `delete` or `delete []` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, without specifying which column exactly you were watching, the number in task manager means nothing. On a modern operating system it's difficult even to *define* what you mean with "used memory" - are we talking about private pages? The working set? Only the stuff that stays in RAM? does reserved but not committed memory count? Who pays for memory shared between processes? Are memory mapped file included?

If you are watching some meaningful metric, it's impossible to see 3 MB of memory used - your object is at least 12 bytes (assuming 32 bit integers and no padding), so 400000 elements will need about 4.58 MB. Also, I'd be surprised if it worked with stack allocation - the default stack size in VC++ is 1 MB, you should already have had a stack overflow.

Anyhow, it is reasonable to expect a different memory usage:

- the stack is (mostly) allocated right from the beginning, so that's memory you nominally consume even without really using it for anything (actually virtual memory and automatic stack expansion makes this a bit more complicated, but it's "true enough");
- the CRT heap is opaque to the task manager: all it sees is the memory given by the operating system to the process, not what the C heap has "really" in use; the heap grows (requesting memory to the OS) more than strictly necessary to be ready for further memory requests - so what you see is how much memory it is ready to give away without further syscalls;
- your "separate allocations" method has a significant overhead. The all-contiguous array you'd get with `new Entry[size]` costs `size*sizeof(Entry)` bytes, plus the heap bookkeeping data (typically a few integer-sized fields); the separated allocations method costs at least `size*sizeof(Entry)` (size of all the "bare elements") plus `size*sizeof(Entry *)` (size of the pointer array) plus `size+1` multiplied by the cost of each allocation. If we assume a 32 bit architecture with a cost of 2 ints per allocation, you quickly see that this costs `size*24+8` bytes of memory, instead of `size*12+8` for the contiguous array in the heap;
- the heap normally really gives away blocks that aren't really the size you asked for, because it manages blocks of fixed size; so, if you allocate single objects like that you are probably paying also for some extra padding - supposing it has 16 bytes blocks, you are paying 4 bytes extra per element by allocating them separately; this moves out memory estimation to `size*28+8`, i.e. an overhead of 16 bytes per each 12-byte element.

Comment: In the taskmanager, there is a column that says **Memory (Private Working Set)**.  That's what I used; I wasn't aware that I could get a more accurate reading.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected it would be something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong, or I don't see how this worked. With `new Entry [count]` you create a new array of `Entry` (type is `Entry*`), yet you assign it to `Entry**`, so I presume you used `new Entry*[count]`.

What you did next was to create another new Entry object on the heap, and storing it in the `globalEntries` array. So you need memory for 400.000 pointers + 400.000 elements. 400.000 pointers take 3 MiB of memory on a 64-bit machine. Additionally, you have 400.000 single Entry allocations, which will all require `sizeof (Entry)` plus potentially some more memory (for the memory manager -- it might have to store the size of allocation, the associated pool, alignment/padding, etc.) These additional book-keeping memory can quickly add up.

If you change your second example to:

```
 Entry* globalEntries;
 globalEntries = new Entry[count];
 for (...) {
     globalEntries [i] = Entry (...);
 }
```

memory usage should be equal to the stack approach.

Of course, ideally you'll use a `std::vector<Entry>`.

Comment: Right.  Sorry, I slipped up on that; I didn't copy it directly from my code, but that is what I had.

Comment: 400 000 pointers on a 64 bit machine is 3 200 000 bytes, which is 3.2 megabytes, not 30.  Same math applies later.  I think you shifted a decimal.

Comment: the three megabytes comment was more of a general estimate.  It might have been closer to five, although I changed the type to a char, and the coordinates to 16-bit ints.

Comment: Removed the last paragraph then :)

Comment: It still doesn't account for the 5-8 fold difference in memory usage.

Comment: I don't know if the extra overhead is directly responsible for *that much* memory increase.  To experiment, I tried only actually filling half of the entries, and the program consumed roughly the same amount of memory.

Comment: @SpikeMF As I said earlier, you probably have some memory leaks. Why don't you check my first comment.